# How to simply display lines of a file - Batch

Tags: batch-file

I am trying to find a easy way to display how many lines of text there is in a text file, but google in some kind of way keeps showing these totally advanced scripts that makes no sence.. as always i try not to keep things to complicated and as minimal as possible.

```
echo +hehe0 > ex.txt
set num=0
:loop
set /a num=%num%+1
echo +hehe%num% >> ex.txt
if %num% equ 6 goto end
findstr /n "+" ex.txt
pause
```

i hope this will make good sence, and help others as well, one love

Answer (score 1):

To display # of lines:

```
type filename|find /c /v ""
```

To assign # of lines to a variable:

```
for /f %%a in ('type filename^|find /c /v "" ') do set var=%%a
```

(`%%a` if within a batchfile; `%a` if directly from the prompt.)